# why am i getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined error even though my web element reference is correct?

Tags: protractor, cucumber, chai, gherkin

I'm getting an error returned when i run a protractor test.

Here is the reference to the webelement in the directories.page.js file:

```
get importErrorsList(){
    return element.all(by.css('[ng-if="error.error.detailMessage"]'));
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the webelement and it's source info:
[image: webelement and source]
And finally here is the step that i am using to reference the webelement, which is returning the error:

```
Then(/^The list of import errors contains this error message: "([^"]*)"$/, function (errorText, callback) {
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(importPageObj.alertMsg), timeouts.EC_TIMEOUT).then(function(){
            browser.wait(() => {  
//the next line causes the error 
expect(directoriesPageObj.importErrorsList.getText()).to.eventually.contain(errorText).and.notify(callback);
                }, timeouts.EC_TIMEOUT).then(() => {
                browser.wait(EC.and(EC.visibilityOf(importPageObj.headerDropDownInWebView), EC.elementToBeClickable(importPageObj.headerDropDownInWebView)), timeouts.EC_TIMEOUT).then(() => {
                    callback();
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

could anyone help me figure out why this isn't working?

Comment: I haven't used getters/setters in awhile - so i can't remember if it's called like a function or not.  Does adding parenthesis to the `importErrorsList` in the `expect` statement fix it?  `expect(directoriesPageObj.importErrorsList().getText())...`

Comment: got this error returned when i added parenthesis to the obect: `TypeError: directoriesPageObj.importErrorsList is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not initialise `directoriesPageObj`. So, before using it you should make:

```
const directoriesPageObj = new DirectoriesPageObj()
```

and after it you can use `directoriesPageObj` variable. For example:

```
Then(/^The list of import errors contains this error message: "([^"]*)"$/, function (errorText, callback) {
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(importPageObj.alertMsg), timeouts.EC_TIMEOUT).then(function(){
            browser.wait(() => {  
const directoriesPageObj = new DirectoriesPageObj();
expect(directoriesPageObj.importErrorsList.getText()).to.eventually.contain(errorText).and.notify(callback);
                }, timeouts.EC_TIMEOUT).then(() => {
                browser.wait(EC.and(EC.visibilityOf(importPageObj.headerDropDownInWebView), EC.elementToBeClickable(importPageObj.headerDropDownInWebView)), timeouts.EC_TIMEOUT).then(() => {
                    callback();
                });
            });
        });
    });
```